# How to bind one variable to 2 params within an sql prepared statement in PHP

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am trying to use the same variable  to bind to 2 params (customerid) in the sql prepared statement. see below:

```
select * from customervisit where ( customerid = ? and frequency in ('Week', 'Month')) or (customerid = ? and frequency in ('Annual') and MONTH(date) = 10 and YEAR(date) = (YEAR(GETDATE()) -1) );

$params = array($customerid, $customerid);
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($this->conn, $sql, $params);
```

Is there a better way to not do this?

```
$params = array($customerid, $customerid);
```

Comment: You could use PDO with named parameters

Comment: Could you precise what is your SQL backend ? A RDBMS ?

Comment: @Zilog80 Yes, it is a RDBMS, mainly Oracle

Comment: `SELECT field2, field3 FROM table WHERE field1 = :field1`    and then in PDO use  
`->bindParam(':field1', $val)`